# How do you find the number of rows in a DataGrid using .net compact framework?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

How do you find the number of rows in a DataGrid using .net compact framework?

Answer (score 4):

Try querying the binding context of the DataGrid: `DataGrid.BindingContext[DataGrid.DataSource].Count`

Or, assuming the data source is a DataTable and you know something about the data source, you can also try `((DataTable)dataGrid1.DataSource).Rows.Count` or the equivalent.

Comment: I am using a DataReader or else I would have found the number of rows from that.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot. We were using VisibleRowCount and running into issues.

Comment: DataGrid.BindingContext[DataGrid.DataSource].Count => is a great answer

Comment: and for the visual basic guys: DirectCast(dataGrid1.DataSource, DataTable).Rows.Count

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a DataReader with a DB SQL call? If so you can use multiple resultsets to return the row count in your SQL call.

Here's a good example of what I'm describing at the link below.

[Determine how many records the DataReader is about to return](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18807)